# proving that a ratio involving factorial of Prime number and another number will be an integer.

Tags: combinatorics

I want to prove that follow ratio 
$$ (p-1)!/r! (p-r)!$$ 
Is an integer. 
P Is a prime number and r is a natural number less than p. 
Thoughts :$$(p-1)!/(p-r)!r! =p.(p -1)!/p.(p-r)!.r! =p! /r! (p-r)!p$$=combination of p things taken r at a time divided by p.
I don't know what to do from here. 
If I factor away (p-r)! From denominator, I get product of r-1 consecutive number divided by r! As $$(p-1)!=p(p-1)(p-2)(p-3)....(p-r+1)(p-r)!$$
I have read a theorem that product of r consecutive integers is divisible by r!. 
Would it help? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\frac{(p-1)!}{r!(p-r)!}=\binom{p}{r}\frac{1}{p}$$
So we need to prove that $p$ divides $\binom{p}{r}$.

We have the identity : 
$$r\binom{p}{r}=p\binom{p-1}{r-1}$$ 
Since $p$ is prime, it does not divide $r$, so it divides $\binom{p}{r}$.

Answer (score 0):

You know that binomial numbers are integers, right? Since your ratio can be written as $\frac{1}{p} \cdot \binom{p}{r}$, it suffices to prove that $\binom{p}{r}$ is divisible by $p$. Do you know how to do this?